# Application crashed on closing peer connection appRTC android

Tags: android, crash, apprtc, webrtc-android, rtcpeerconnection

I have implemented appRTC in my app but changed its flow to multiple guests with one host (like a conference meeting etc.). But the issue I am facing is when I disconnects from host side the app got crashed. It also shows different weird exceptions on log related to SQLite and constraints. I have been working on this for a week but couldn't fount anything.
This one I got this time.

2020-08-11 18:10:01.856 19916-19916/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.facebook.appmanager/databases/androidx.work.workdb'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

The code I used to close Peer Connection is below:

```
private void disconnect() {
    try{
        if (appRtcClient != null) {
            try{
                appRtcClient.disconnectFromRoom();
                appRtcClient = null;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (FirebaseRTCClient.myId.equals("host")){
            activityRunning = false;
            if (appRtcClient != null) {
                try{
                    appRtcClient.disconnectFromRoom();
                    appRtcClient = null;
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i<peerConnectionClientsList.size(); i++){
                    if (peerConnectionClientsList.get(i) != null) {
                        peerConnectionClientsList.get(i).close();
                        peerConnectionClient = null;
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            if (localRender != null) {
                localRender.release();
                localRender = null;
            }
            if (videoFileRenderer != null) {
                videoFileRenderer.release();
                videoFileRenderer = null;
            }
            if (remoteRenderScreen != null) {
                remoteRenderScreen.release();
                remoteRenderScreen = null;
            }
            if (audioManager != null) {
                audioManager.close();
                audioManager = null;
            }
            if (iceConnected && !isError) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
            } else {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            }
            finish();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnect Error: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and closeInternal() :

```
public void closeInternal() {
try{
  if (factory != null && peerConnectionParameters.aecDump) {
    factory.stopAecDump();
  }
  Log.d(TAG, "Closing peer connection.");
  statsTimer.cancel();

    try{
        for (int i = 0; i<peerConnectionList.size(); i++){
            if (peerConnectionList.get(i)!=null){
                peerConnectionList.get(i).close();
                peerConnection = null;
                pcConstraints=null;
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


Log.d(TAG, "Closing audio source.");
if (audioSource != null) {
  audioSource.dispose();
  audioSource = null;
}
Log.d(TAG, "Closing video source.");
if (videoSource != null) {
  videoSource.dispose();
  videoSource = null;
}
  options = null;
  Log.d(TAG, "Closing peer connection done.");
  events.onPeerConnectionClosed();
  PeerConnectionFactory.stopInternalTracingCapture();
  PeerConnectionFactory.shutdownInternalTracer();
}catch (Exception e){
  Toast.makeText(context, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
  }
```